# Is there a difference between CBC and CFB modes in AES?

Tags: php, aes

Quoting [myforwik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb/1220869#1220869), `CBC, OFB and CFB are identical, however OFB/CFB is better because you only need encryption and not decryption, which can save code space.`

I want a pure implementation of AES CFB in PHP. I specifically do NOT want `mcrypt`.

I therefore turned to PHPSecLib. However, as per [the documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/crypt.html#crypt_dependencies), the library only supports ECB and CBC.

I do not think myforwik meant that CBC and CFB can be used interchangeably... So, a) is there a CFB implementation out there<del>, or b) can I (easily) implement CFB mode from PHPSecLib's CBC implementation</del>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the latest CVS of phpseclib.  It supports CTR, CFB and OFB, in addition to CBC and ECB.  I assume the documentation will be updated when a new version is released.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should always remember to check the repo, but sometimes time makes me forget...

Answer (score 1):

[CBC, OFB and CFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_modes) are not identical - though there are similarities.  If they were identical, they would not have different names.

If you want AES + CFB, you cannot use AES + CBC to achieve the result.  You will have to find a way to get AES + CFB implemented if it is not already available.

Comment: That's what I thought. That's b) taken care of, then.

Comment: @passcod: I've gone and annotated the x-ref.