# Transfer secure data, android to server

Tags: android, security

I'm working on an android project that gets the students marks from the website.
How to send the user name and the password securely? (I need some codes)
If I use the ***sharedpreferences*** to save the user name and the password, is that secure?

Note:

1. I have no access to the database (the web developer will print the data in the web page `<a herf="http://saif-test.zxq.net/subject.php?name=2013"> example </a>`). User name and password will send like `"www.example.com/marks?user=myusername&pass=password"` or ***UrlEncodedFormEntity(data)***  and the app handled the received data.
2. The website has ***SSL*** connection

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244318/android-sharedpreference-security

Comment: @robotoaster thanx. The link helps me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharedPreferences are pretty secure to store credentials, but it would more secure if you could store them encrypted. So once the user entered his credentials, store them encrypted. The encrypt/decrypt key could be computed at runtime based on some unique device information. That is up to you.

Second, if you have SSL on website, then I don't see reasons to worry when it comes to sending data over https.
For above reason, I wouldn't make any requests that contain user credentials in URI, but rather send them over encrypted POST. The http engine will do automatically that for you if you're using https/ssl.

I don't see what code would you need further on ... A very good post can be found on [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) for https, when it comes to encryption, you could base on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622367/what-are-best-practices-for-using-aes-encryption-in-android), while [SharedPreferences are trivial to use](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Good luck!