# Java AES En/decryption for a String

Tags: java, encryption, initialization

I have found an useful AES256 implementation to en/decrypt strings, all work fine except the fact i have to store the initialization vector (IV) for the decoding.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
ivBytes = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
```

All there any (secure) alternative methods maybe without CBC, because with CBC i have to store an IV (and in my case i have to share the IV which is really not secure).
I have read an article on this platform concerning it´s possible to encode without CBC but that´s not a good idea because of dictionary attacks.

so, are there any alternatives to encode a string with aes256 (without storing **additional data** like IV, or salt arrays)?

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind an `IV` is to use a **distinct new random one** for every encryption (with the same `key`).

This is very important to ensure the the security of cipher-modes such as *CTR* or *CBC* which would not be secure at all without an `IV`. Also when using the same `key` to encrypt the same `message` twice it will result in two distinct ciphertexts (since the two `IV`s were distinct).

In short, you should **always** use an `IV`.

Usually you just prepend them to the ciphertexts and then extract them before encryption, so you don't have to store them individually.

Comment: +1 The key point here being... the IV is not sensitive information, provided it is randomly chosen each time. The same is true for salt values.

Comment: @i_turo thank you for the answer, it works the same way like in example #1  from here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622367/what-are-best-practices-for-using-aes-encryption-in-android

"return ivHex + encryptedHex;"

i have to accept that it´s not a lack of serurity to add the IV to the encoded message.