# Can someone explain the difference between "AND" and "&" in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm pretty darn new to Access developement. Yesterday, I developed a query and in the WHERE portion, I used "&" as in :

```
WHERE ((condition A Is Null) & (condition B Is Null))
```

It returned 53 hits.

Then I changed it to

```
WHERE ((condition A Is Null) AND (condition B Is Null))
```

and got 71 hits.

I know it has to do with 'bitwise and' vs 'logical and', but can someone take a moment to explain this to me in noobish (English)?

Comment: What version of MS Access is this?  When I try, I get the result of concatenation, i.e., `-1-1`, or `-10`, because `&` is the string concatenation operator.  You should just always use `AND`.

Comment: Access 07.  I ran a query to match credit card numbers using only the last 4 numbers. Have to do a join to see if the card's last numbers and the employee number don't exist, then I know it's a new card to add to the DB.

Comment: As @mellamokb said, you want AND. The & is the VBA/Jet/ACE concatenator. Note also WHERE, not WHILE.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197652/sql-if-column-a-is-null-then-use-column-bs-value-to-compute-column-c noting in particular the comments.

Comment: Damn, my edits suck today..... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` is a logical operator.  `&` is a concatenation operator.  Review [Table of operators](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/table-of-operators-HA010235862.aspx) for more details about the various operators available in Access 2007.

To see the differences in action, start with this as table `WeinerDog`.

```
id field1 field2
 1 a
 2        y
 3
```

The blanks in the `field1` and `field2` columns represent Null values.

Next run this query:

```
SELECT
    WeinerDog.id,
    WeinerDog.field1,
    WeinerDog.field2,
    (WeinerDog.field1 Is Null)
        & (WeinerDog.field2 Is Null) AS concat_result
FROM WeinerDog
WHERE
    (WeinerDog.field1 Is Null) & (WeinerDog.field2 Is Null);
```

That query should give you this result set:

```
id field1 field2 concat_result
 1 a             0-1
 2        y      -10
 3               -1-1
```

Examine the `concat_result` column.  It contains strings which are the truth values of the 2 expressions concatenated together.  Those truth values are either True (-1) or False (0).  However, since the result of concatenation must be a string, the numeric truth values are first cast as strings before they are joined together.

Then examine the `WHERE` clause.  The db engine will give you all rows for which the `WHERE` clause evaluates as `True`.  And actually, not just -1, but any non-Null value other than zero can stand in for `True`.  As you can see from the `concat_result` column, none of those rows will be evaluated as zero (`False`) by the `WHERE` clause ... so all rows in the table will be included in the query result set.

If you change the `WHERE` clause to substitute `AND` for `&`, the query will return only the `WeinerDog` row (id=3) which has Null for both `field1` and `field2`.

```
WHERE
    (WeinerDog.field1 Is Null) AND (WeinerDog.field2 Is Null);
```