# Converting Coldfusion encryption code to C# (again)

Tags: c#, encryption, coldfusion, base64

Once again I'm tasked with converting ColdFusion code used for a single sign-on to C# and am running short on time.  This one is completely different than my question that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848994/converting-coldfusion-encryption-code-to-c-sharp), so I'm back to being in over my head.

The original ColdFusion code was executed in a <cfscript> tag.  I've replaced the src and pwd variables with abbreviated placeholders just to obscure their actual values:

```
//create a key to be used
src="xxx";
pwd="abc";

// Base64 Decoding the key
base64Decoder = createObject("java", "sun.misc.BASE64Decoder");
desKeyData = base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(pwd);


// Initialize the constructor of DESedeKeySpec with private key
KeySpec=createObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec");
KeySpec=KeySpec.init(desKeyData);

// Generate the secret key using SecretKeyFactory
keyFac=createObject("java", "javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory").getInstance("DESede");
secretKey =keyFac.generateSecret(KeySpec);


// Get CIPHER OBJ ready to use
decodecipher = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Cipher").getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
decodecipher.init(2, secretKey);

encodecipher = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Cipher").getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

encodecipher.init(1, secretKey);

stringBytes = toString(src).getBytes("UTF8");
raw = encodecipher.doFinal(stringBytes);

// Base64Encoding of generated cipher
cipherText=ToBase64(raw);
```

I also have a document from the other party that outlines the steps for creating the single sign-on as follows:

Creating the encrypted token

- Create the plain text (this corresponds to the variable src above, and that part I've done successfully in C#)
- Pad the plain text
- Decode the key (the key corresponds to the variable pwd above, and must be base 64 decoded; I think I've successfully gotten up to this point as well.)
- Perform the encryption (use the decoded key obtained above and the plain text to do the encryption)
- Encode the cipher text (url encoded)

I have the BouncyCastle libraries installed and am trying to make use of those, but I'm stuck on the actual encryption step. So far the beginning of my C# conversion looks like this (once again the token and key have abbreviated placeholders to obscure the actual values):

```
//steps omitted here to create src string
string token = "xxx";
string key = "abc";
byte[] decodedKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
```

I know that's not a whole lot to go on, but I've tried so many things that haven't worked that I've lost track.  Eventually when I get to the piece where I'm initializing the cipher, I assume I need something like this:

```
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new DesEdeEngine());
```

Thanks very much for any suggestions/examples.

**Update:**

Thanks to the very helpful answer below, I was able to get this working using the following code:

```
string token = "xxx";
string key = "abc";

byte[] base64DecodedKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
byte[] inputBytesToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);

// initialize for EBC mode and PKCS5/PKCS7 padding
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new DesEdeEngine());
KeyParameter param = new KeyParameter(base64DecodedKeyBytes);
cipher.Init(true, param);

// encrypt and encode as base64
byte[] encryptedBytesToken = cipher.DoFinal(inputBytesToken);
string tokenBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytesToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This one is completely different

Not so much ;-)  You already answered your own question.

Do not let the java code throw you. Ignoring some unused variables, it is doing exactly the same thing as `encrypt()` on your other thread - except with "TripleDES" instead of "Blowfish". `encrypt()` hides a lot of the complexity, but internally it is does the same thing - using those same java classes FWIW. That means you can use the same C# code. As you already guessed, you just need to swap out the crypto engine:

```
....
// initialize for EBC mode and PKCS5/PKCS7 padding
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new DesEdeEngine());
...
```

**Update:**

Just to elaborate a bit, when you use `encrypt( someUTF8String, base64Key, algorithm, encoding)`, CF performs the same steps as your java code internally:

1. Decodes the key from base64, and creates a KeySpec object for the given algorithm, ie

   `// Base64 Decoding the key
   // CF may use a different decoder, but the overall process is the same
   base64Decoder = createObject("java", "sun.misc.BASE64Decoder");
   ....
   secretKey =keyFac.generateSecret(KeySpec);`
2. Next it extracts the UTF-8 bytes of the plain text, ie

   `stringBytes = toString(src).getBytes("UTF8");`
3. CF then creates a cipher, which pads and encrypts the plain text, ie:

   `encodeCipher = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Cipher").getInstance(algorithm);
   encodeCipher.init(1, secretKey); // 1 - ENCRYPT_MODE
   raw = encodeCipher.doFinal(stringBytes);`
4. Finally, CF encodes the encrypted bytes as base64, ie:

   `cipherText=ToBase64(raw);`

So as you can see, the java code and `encrypt` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!  At least I wasn't terribly off with the cipher initialization. :)

I'm still a little unsure about the encryption part though - in the code from my other question, I only had the static key, but in this one I've got a key and a dynamically generated encrypted token, so I'm not quite sure how to combine both of those in the encryption step.

Comment: EDIT: *combine both of those in the encryption step.* Maybe my brain is tired, but I am not seeing the full picture in what you posted.  The original CF/java code is just a basic `encrypt()`. Run the C# code with the TripleDES class and you will get the same result. Could they mean "use the code above to generate a 'key' to be used for the "Blowfish" encryption"?

Comment: Any luck? It seemed like you were simply trying to convert the cfscript code. If not, could you post more details because it sounds like there is a piece of the puzzle missing.

Comment: Yes, I was finally able to get this working just now - thank you again for your help and the very clear explanation, I really appreciate it!  I didn't realize that, as you pointed out, encrypt() does so many of those steps behind the scenes; the CF code looked so different to me, and I was getting hung up trying to recreate each piece.  I might have actually been better off trying to translate the instructions directly into C# without the CF code for reference. :)  I've updated my post with the successful code.

Comment: Yes, for the most part CF uses java's core crypto library. Since there is only one way to use that API, `encrypt()`uses the same methods internally as any other java application. Glad I could help :)