# Choose of AES ECB in specifications

Tags: security, networking, encryption, cryptography, aes

I was reading the  [the specification of LoRaWAN](https://www.lora-alliance.org/portals/0/specs/LoRaWAN%20Specification%201R0.pdf), a network for IoT which uses AES for the security, when I saw this:

> Note: The network server uses an AES decrypt operation in ECB
>   mode to encrypt the join-accept message so that the end-device can
>   use an AES encrypt operation to decrypt the message. This way an
>   end-device only has to implement AES encrypt but not AES decrypt.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb), along with several other sources*, indicates that ECB should not be used. The answer of the question linked add that "OFB/CFB is better because you only need encryption and not decryption, which can save code space". So why have the conceptors of LoRaWAN choosen to use ECB?

*: Wikipedia gives [a striking example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) with a picture ciphered with AES-ECB.

Comment: If they use a new key for each encryption, then this would be fine. Are they? (You read the specification after all)

Comment: Nop, if I understood correctly keys are calculated once.

Comment: in the specifications, there is that: `An end-device has to go through a new join procedure every time it has lost the session context information.`. I don't know how the session context information can be lost.

Answer (score 0):

From my (quick) reading of the specification, the same device-specific key ("Appkey") is used to "decrypt" the plaintext message at the server.  I put "decrypt" in quotes, because it's using AES decrypt to actually encrypt the message; the receiving device, which only needs to implement AES encrypt, can then decrypt the ciphertext.  Remember that these are very resource-constrained, low-power devices.

Anyway, to answer your question -- I'm basing this off of section 6.2.5 of the specification -- it appears that many of the fields are somewhat predictable, and the key isn't changing, so they are relying on the uniqueness of the 24-bit nonce (nonce = number used once, ever).  2^24 is approximately 16 million.  If the nonce is ever re-used (even accidentally, for example if it is randomly generated and there is a nonce collision (just google "Birthday Paradox") ) you have a real security problem.

I haven't spent enough time w/ the specification to further understand/criticize the security measures, but I'd be willing to bet there are some implementations using rand() for the nonce (sad face) or even worse, a hard-coded value (really sad face).