# Coldfusion Encryption and Perl Decryption

Tags: perl, encryption, coldfusion

I have a situation where I need to encrypt content in Coldfusion and then decrypt in Perl. Here's a sample Coldfusion code:

```
<cfscript>
  input = "Amidst the roar of liberated Rome, Of nations freed, and the world overjoy'd";
  encryptionKey = "8kbD1Cf8TIMvm8SRxNNfaQ==";
  encryptedInput = encrypt( input, encryptionKey, "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "hex" );
  writeOutput( "Encrypted Input: #encryptedInput# <br />" );
</cfscript>
```

This produces:

```
27B0F3EB1286FFB462BDD3F14F5A41724DF1ED888F1BEFA7174CA981C7898ED2EF841A15CDE4332D030818B9923A2DBA0C68C8352E128A0744DF5F9FA955D3C72469FEFDAE2120DE5D74319ED666DDD0
```

And the Perl:

```
use 5.24.1;
use Crypt::ECB qw(encrypt_hex);

my $input = "Amidst the roar of liberated Rome, Of nations freed, and the world overjoy'd";
my $encryption_key = "8kbD1Cf8TIMvm8SRxNNfaQ==";
my $encrypted_input = encrypt_hex($encryption_key, 'Rijndael', $input);
say $encrypted_input;
```

This produces:

```
e220ff2efe5d41e92237622ba969f35158d20e2c9c44995d44136d928d517462980321d4d6193fe62dc942fd717128442972524207777366954e5ceb2d1812ac997e06767a27d6a0145176d717c3836b
```

Why is the encrypted content different? Does anyone have any insights into this?

Comment: Next, ColdFusion uses your base64 key as a literal string value and not a base64 value. As @mob noted below, PERL is decoding the base64 encryption key.

Comment: For the ColdFusion code, "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" is not a documented encryption type for the encrypt() in ColdFusion. Though using this value, ColdFusion does use AES. (AES: NIST FIPS-197)  Here's a list of valid parameters in ColdFusion for encrypt() https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html

Comment: @WilGeno - Actually it is the opposite :-). CF *does* treat it as base64 encoded. PERL does not. Also, though the latest CF docs don't enumerate all of the types, AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding is valid for the underlying java lib. It used to be documented somewhere in the old Adobe docs. Can't recall where though.

Comment: Note that your code uses seriously broken encryption since you don't use an IV (which should be completely random each time)

Comment: True. Like @ikegami suggested, you should use CBC and a different IV each time for better security.

Comment: See for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb#22958889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encryption key is base64 encoded, but `Crypt::ECB` expects a raw byte string (this isn't clear from the docs, though).

```
use Convert::Base64;
...

my $encryption_key = decode_base64("8kbD1Cf8TIMvm8SRxNNfaQ==");
...
```

New output:

```
27b0f3eb1286ffb462bdd3f14f5a41724df1ed888f1befa7174ca981c7898ed2ef841a15cde4332d030818b9923a2dba0c68c8352e128a0744df5f9fa955d3c72469fefdae2120de5d74319ed666ddd0
```

Comment: @DonJuanInHeaven - Also note, CF always returns hex in upper case. Though both should decode to the same value.

Comment: Thank you @mob, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: @mob - I'm not famliar with Perl. Does it support CBC mode too, like ikegami mentioned above?